# How to draw an arrow from fps contoller in unity3d with c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to know how to attach an arrow to show what direction the fps controller is facing.  I am using the below method to get the power I will use to throw the stone.

```
 void OnGUI() {
        hSbarValue = GUI.HorizontalScrollbar(new Rect(25, 25, 100, 30), Mathf.PingPong(Time.time*5.0f, 19), 1.0F, 0.0F, 19.0F);
    }
```

I would also like the arrow to change the its size depending on the power off that method.

I dont have a clue how to do this so any help would be appreciated.

Thanking you

Answer (score 0):

3D Arrow?  Create an arrow GameObject (you'll have to create the model yourself), then just use **LookAt** to point towards your objective:

```
void Update(){
    arrowObject.transform.LookAt(target);
}
```

Size you can just scale:

```
void Update(){
    arrowObject.transform.LookAt(target);
    arrowObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(scale,scale,1.0f);
}
```

For my example my arrow object was facing down the Z axis which is why I only scale X/Y, to thin/fatten but not lengthen the arrow.  That same assumption is why **transform.LookAt** works, my arrow is already pointing down the gameobject's forward vector.